# Using jmeter not all requests processed in database, but in jmeter listener shows all requests hits the server

Tags: jmeter, master-slave

Using jmeter, I have 10000 users need to hit the server and to respond back with in 40 sec.

During execution (in distributed mode) only 600 users really hitting (Checked in db) in server.

But in AGGREGATE REPORT it shows all requests hits the server.

What is the issue behind this? why the number of requests hits the server isn't consistent between db and jmeter listener?

Comment: Have you used 'ResponseAssertion'?

Comment: There's a different between hit the server and hit the database,no? why you tag it as master slave?

Comment: i know this is an old question. but have you found any solution to this issue? i've got the similar problem where the result tree shows success but the db doesn't get affected and the data isn't inserted

Answer (score 0):

Probably your test configuration is a little bit wrong.

JMeter acts as follows:

1. JMeter starts all the threads (virtual users) within the bounds of ramp-up period specified in the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration
2. Each thread (virtual user) starts executing [samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down
3. When there are no more samplers to execute and no more loops to iterate the thread is being shut down.

You can check how many threads were actually active using [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) or the same chart of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

So you may run into a situation when some samplers have already done their work and some haven't been yet started. Basically you need to provide enough loops to make sure all 10k threads will be up and running for the required test duration.

See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) guide for more information.

Comment: I have only one thread group with 10000 virtual users(Using distributed so no of vrtual users is 100 with 10 slaves) In jmeter aggregate reports all samples get passed with0%error. While checking in db only 700 entires are inserted